# The multi-checker in kendo-grid-column is not displaying items

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

The items for multi-checker are not displayed when I run the application locally, however, I tried to reproduce the bug on a stackblitz with the exact same situation but it turns to work on the stackblitz but not locally on my machine:
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3bzgmo?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

you can see the **Metric Type** column, when clicking on the filter menu icon, it opens with some items in the dropdown list.

However, the only error I am getting locally is about license activation failed. does anyone know if license issue could lead for such error in the development mode?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not about license, check if kendo versions aren't mismatched.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).